# Vb.Net Take snapshot of streaming webcam video (over internet)

Tags: vb.net, web, video-streaming, screenshot

I have a video streaming of a security webcam. I'd need to take screenshots at a as high as possible resolution at regular intervals.

Option 1 would be to fullscreen the video and take regular screenshots and save them but I'd have the computer busy and couldnt work on it anymore.

Option 2 would be to somehow capture the webstream, and extract a screenshot from the stream.

Are there any better otpions? How could i capture screenshots from the stream?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that can help you taking a screen shot and automatically saving it.  OPTION 1.

```
    Dim screenShot As New Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)

    Dim g = Graphics.FromImage(screenShot)
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, screenShot.Size)
    g.Dispose()

    screenShot.Save("C:\test.bmp")
```

You could put this in a timer or something and just add like the date or an incremented number to the end of the file name.

For option 2 you might have to resort to some third party program to be able to do what you want. As far as I know, the only way to get a capture of your screen is to have it visible. Maybe I'll poke around at it. You've got me curious now.